# On a question in page 42 of Cartan and Eilenberg's Book "Homological algebra"

Tags: homological-algebra

In page 42 of their book, there is a setence
 "in this case, it can be easily seen that the homomorphism "$\overline{u}$:Ker(T(M)$\rightarrow$ T(P))$\rightarrow$ T(M)" is defined by inclusion". I can not check it, can someone who read that book explain that? Thanks.

I think by a "snake lemma" type diagram chase, the homomorphism above should be multiplication by -1. The question I ask is as follows：

Let $R$ be a ring. When there is an exact sequence of left $R$-modules, $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow P\xrightarrow{f} B\rightarrow 0$ with $P$ a projective $R$-module, we can form  exact sequences 
$0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{f_1} M\xrightarrow{g_1} P\rightarrow 0$, 
and $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{f_2} M\xrightarrow{g_2} P\rightarrow 0$, where $M$ is a submodule of $P\oplus P$ consisting of all pairs $(p_1,p_2)$ such that $f(p_1)=f(p_2)$, and $f_1(a)=(a,0),g_1(p_1,p_2)=p_2$  $f_2(a)=(0,a),g_2(p_1,p_2)=p_1$. If T is a covariant additive functor, does $T(f_1)=T(f_2)$, or $T(f_1)=-T(f_2)$?

Comment: There could be someone perfectly capable of answering this question but doesn’t own the book.   You should add all context into your question.

Comment: What is T(P) for example?

Comment: I don't know if this is the source of your confusion, but there is apparently an error in a proof on page 42. See Flanders, Harley,
"Satellites of half exact functors, a correction,"
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 15 (1964), 834–837.